# Filtro de Mixitup.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy usando mixitup para un menú de un restaurante, pero quiero que cuando se cargue la pagina se filte solo en una de las categorías del menú en lugar de mostrar todos los platos, es decir no quiero la cateria "all" sino que lo primero que se muestre es "areperia".

```
<ul id="filter-list" class="clearfix">
                <li class="filter active" data-filter="areperia">Areperia/Starters</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter="parrilla" >La parrilla - BBQ</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter="desayunos" >All day brekkie specials</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter="limitados" >Limited editions</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter="pizzeria" >La pizzeria - Pizzas</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter="ensaladas" >Ensaladas - Salads</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter="limon" >Ensaladas de limon - Lime salads</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter="taqueria" >La taqueria</li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter="dulces"> La reposteria - Sweets </li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter="bebidas">La cafeteria - Coffees,teas,driks</li>
    </ul><!-- @end #filter-list -->
    <ul id="portfolio">
        <li class="item areperia">
            <h3><B>Arepas</B><br> BBQ roasted corn breads (butter optional)</h3>
            <h2 class="precio">2 for $5</h2>
          </li>
        <li class="item areperia">
            <h3>Arepa rainbow<br> 3 corn breads of spinach,sweet popato & beetroot</h3>
            <h2 class="precio centro">$10</h2>
          </li>
        <li class="item areperia">
            <h3>Yuca frita<br> Deep fried cassava root</h3>
            <h2 class="precio">3 for $5</h2>
          </li>
        <li class="item parrilla">
            <h3>Pinchos Vegetarianos<br>BBQ begie + haloumi sticks</h3>
            <h2 class="precio">2 for $10</h2>
           </li>
        <li class="item parrilla">
                <h3>Mazorca<br>BBQ roasted corn</h3>
                <h2 class="precio">$5</h2>
            </li>        
</ul>
```

y mi js es,aqui no estoy haciendo ninguna modificacion extraña pero ya intente con varias cosas y nada

```
$(function(){
    $('#portfolio').mixitup({
        targetSelector: '.item',
        transitionSpeed: 350,
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el load para decirle que filtro cargar

```
$('#portafolio').mixItUp({
   targetSelector: '.item',
   load: {
     filter: '.category-1'
   }
});
```